# Search keyword with selectable exposed filters

Tags: 7, views, forms

I'm trying to make a search view with one textfields and two checkbox filters (body, tags). The search text would only search the selected fields and would show results as summaries.

I've tried combined fields filters in Views, but the filters selected are all enabled. Is there was a way to toggle the filters via checkbox?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the module that you are looking for....

[Better Exposed Filters](https://www.drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters)

> The Better Exposed Filters module replaces the Views' default single-
>   or multi-select boxes with radio buttons or checkboxes, respectively.
>   Description fields and Select All/None links can be added to exposed
>   filters to make for a better user experience.
>
> Views Filters is a powerful tool to refine the results returned by a
>   given view. When you expose a filter, you allow the user to interact
>   with the view making it easy to build a customized, advanced search.
>   For example, exposing the node type field as a filter lets your site
>   visitor limit their search queries to just blog entries. Better
>   Exposed Filters gives you greater control over the rendering of
>   exposed filters.
>
> Why use this module? Because it provides a better user experience than
>   the default option. Try telling a client that they should click on an
>   option, then scroll to the next option and ctrl+click on it. Don't
>   just click 'cause you'll lose your first selection. Oh, and ctrl+click
>   again to unselect an option... Yeah, not user friendly.

Comment: Sadly BEF cannot, to my knowledge, give me the option of searching by either Article tags, body or title.